# Call an env constant in a middleware file on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to call an .env constant from a Middleware file using Laravel, but I'm only getting Constant expression contains invalid operation.

This is my actual code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        env("TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN") . '/webhook'
    ];
}
```

Comment: that expression can't be evaluated at compile time. you can not set that initial value like that.

Comment: also you don't touch `env` vars outside of config files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means that **default values for class/object properties have to be constant in PHP**. This is because their values are determined at compile/parse time, not at runtime. This means you're not allowed to call any functions.

However, you can do that in the constructor of the class. Add the following function to **VerifyCsrfToken** class:

```
public function __construct(Application $app, Encrypter $encrypter) {
    parent::__construct($app, $encrypter);
    $this->except = [
      env("TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN") . '/webhook'
    ];
}
```

Make sure you have the following **use** statements at the beginning of the file:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter;
```